# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Half in Stable Diffusion

Tags: python, error-handling, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

I am currently using Kangle Kurnel using Python version 3.7

It kept saying RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Half

installed packs

accelerate                            0.12.0
torch                                 1.9.1+cu111
torchaudio                            0.9.1
torchmetrics                          0.11.0
torchtext                             0.12.0
torchvision                           0.10.1+cu111
transformers                          4.26.0

Here is my code

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
import torch
import poetpy
import random
import os
import datetime
import gradio as gr
import time

model_id = "prompthero/openjourney-v2"
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe = pipe.to("cuda")

def gen_image(requested_poem):
    count = 1

    poem =poetpy.get_poetry("title,author", requested_poem)

    for j in range(0, count) :
        try:
            print("In Process")
            req_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
            print(poem)
            title = poem[0]["title"]
            lines = poem[0]["lines"]
            author = poem[0]["author"]

            prompt = ""
            for line in lines:
                prompt+=line+" "
            
            print(title)
            # ai

            image = pipe(prompt).images[0]

            if os.path.exists("./gen_imgs/"+author) == False:
                os.mkdir("./gen_imgs/"+author)
            else:
                pass

            file_path = "./gen_imgs/"+author+"/"+str(title.replace("?","").replace(".","").replace('"',"").replace("/","").replace("*","").replace("\\","").replace("<","").replace(">", "").replace("|", "")) + " " + req_time + ".png"

            image.save(file_path)

        except IndexError:
            j = 0
            break
        except KeyError:
            j = 0
            
            break

    print("Session Terminated")
    
    return image, (author + " - " + title)



requested_poem = "the Raven;Edgar allan poe" # "Title;Author"

gen_image(requested_poem)
'''

app = gr.Interface(
    gen_image,
    title = "PoemJourney by coding_ms",
    inputs = [
        gr.Textbox(label = '그림으로 바꾸고 싶은 시(영문 반드시) Example) The Raven;Edgar Allan Poe')
    ],
    outputs = [
        gr.Image(),
        gr.Text()
    ]
)

app.launch(share=True, debug=True)
'''
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_24/1234688772.py in <module>
     60 requested_poem = "the Raven;Edgar allan poe" # "Title;Author"
     61 
---> 62 gen_image(requested_poem)
     63 '''
     64 

/tmp/ipykernel_24/1234688772.py in gen_image(requested_poem)
     33             # ai
     34 
---> 35             image = pipe(prompt).images[0]
     36 
     37             if os.path.exists("./gen_imgs/"+author) == False:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     26         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     27             with self.__class__():
---> 28                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     29         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     30 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/diffusers/pipelines/stable_diffusion/pipeline_stable_diffusion.py in __call__(self, prompt, height, width, num_inference_steps, guidance_scale, negative_prompt, num_images_per_prompt, eta, generator, latents, prompt_embeds, negative_prompt_embeds, output_type, return_dict, callback, callback_steps)
    572             negative_prompt,
    573             prompt_embeds=prompt_embeds,
--> 574             negative_prompt_embeds=negative_prompt_embeds,
    575         )
    576 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/diffusers/pipelines/stable_diffusion/pipeline_stable_diffusion.py in _encode_prompt(self, prompt, device, num_images_per_prompt, do_classifier_free_guidance, negative_prompt, prompt_embeds, negative_prompt_embeds)
    288             prompt_embeds = self.text_encoder(
    289                 text_input_ids.to(device),
--> 290                 attention_mask=attention_mask,
    291             )
    292             prompt_embeds = prompt_embeds[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, position_ids, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    730             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
    731             return_dict=return_dict,
--> 732         )
    733 
    734         last_hidden_state = encoder_outputs[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, position_ids, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    651                     causal_attention_mask,
    652                 )
--> 653             else:
    654                 layer_outputs = encoder_layer(
    655                     hidden_states,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py in forward(self, inputs_embeds, attention_mask, causal_attention_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    580     """
    581 
--> 582     def __init__(self, config: CLIPConfig):
    583         super().__init__()
    584         self.config = config

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, causal_attention_mask, output_attentions)
    323 
    324         if attn_output.size() != (bsz * self.num_heads, tgt_len, self.head_dim):
--> 325             raise ValueError(
    326                 f"`attn_output` should be of size {(bsz, self.num_heads, tgt_len, self.head_dim)}, but is"
    327                 f" {attn_output.size()}"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, causal_attention_mask, output_attentions)
    258         return tensor.view(bsz, seq_len, self.num_heads, self.head_dim).transpose(1, 2).contiguous()
    259 
--> 260     def forward(
    261         self,
    262         hidden_states: torch.Tensor,

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Half
```

I tried install newer updated versions of transformers and torch - not worked.

Comment: Try changing torch.float16 to torch.float32